Docker on WSL2 (Windows) bind mount and restricted user
I have this my Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:20.04

RUN    groupadd -g 65533 user \
    && useradd -r -u 65533 -g 65533 user \
    && mkdir -p /application \
    && chown -R user:user /application \
    && chmod 777 /application

USER user

WORKDIR "/application"

CMD [ "/bin/bash" ]

and build it with
docker build -t myapp .

and run in
docker run -it --rm -v ./mymnt:/application/mnt myapp /bin/bash

inside the countainer I try to create a file inside the mount
touch mnt/sassa

and get an access denied
touch: cannot touch 'mnt/sassa': Permission denied

I can't put my windows user inside a docker group. I am on a company machine. But according the administration I have admin rights.
I can have given the directory al possible rights.
I have influence how the Dockerfile is looking like.
How can I manage that my container has write access with user rights in my bind mount?

My issue was that I was using the cygwin shell.
I tried this image with a volume mount and got also the issue to write to it.
I startet plain ubuntu image and gave inside the volume rights 777 to a folder inside.
Then again I started the restricted container and tried to write to the volume mount with same result.
After a while I tried pure windows cmd and my problems where gone.
